# Solving a matrix equation with very small inputs

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, equation-solving, numerical-stability, precision

I'm programming in Matlab and  in my program I need to solve a system `Ax=b`, where `A` is a `m` by `m` square matrix with very small entries. If `m` increases, the entries of `A` become smaller.

`A` is a sparse matrix, so I rename this matrix with the function `sparse` of Matlab: `B=sparse(A)`.

Can I use a special method to solve `Bx=b` without underflow or numerical errors?

Comment: I guess you can use [`vpasolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpasolve.html#bt5sqi5-2_1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Parag S. Chandakkar you can resort to `vpasolve`. First let us build a system with a poorly conditioned matrix

```
n = 10;
A = hilb(n)
b = randn(n, 1);
```

The usual way to solve this system is by calling

```
x = A\b;
```

while the one with `vpasolve` is

```
xs = sym('x', [n 1]);
sol = vpasolve(A*xs==b);
```